# jqGrid: How to Lock and Unlock the Grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am working with the jqGrid.

**Quick Summary:**

In summary I want to Lock (make no rows selectable) and also Unlock (make rows selectable).  Both of these tasks must be done on the client side.

**More Detail:**

Basically, once a user selects a row for editing, I want to Lock out the grid so the user cannot select another row until he/she either commits the changes or cancel the changes.

Once the user commits the changes or cancel the changes, then I want to Unlock the grid to allow the user to select another row for editing.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,

R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

$("#gridName").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Comment: that works only on the style of the grid for me. And you need to set boolean values to disable/enable it. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code will give a disable look to the jqgrid :

```
$("#gridName").attr('disabled', true);
```

This code will re-enable a regular look to the jqgrid :

```
("#gridName").attr('disabled', false);
```

But it will only work on the look but not the selectability of the rows, and it's not really documented, so it might lead to undefined behavior.

To disable the selection, the suggested way is to use a third party input blocker like [JQuery BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block). It works on the entire page or elements of the page.

For example to block input :

```
$("#gridName").block({ message: null });
```

and unblock :

```
$("#gridName").unblock();
```